# EXTJS & PHP Upload file2

Tags: extjs

I use the UploadFile example in EXTJS (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/file-upload.html) and i have error.

ExtJS:

```
 var loadfile = new Ext.FormPanel({
    fileUpload: true,
    width: 500,
    frame: true,
    title: 'Добавить фотографию',
    autoHeight: true,
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
    labelWidth: 50,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '95%',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        id: 'form-file',
        emptyText: 'Выберите фотографию',
        fieldLabel: 'Фото',
        name: 'userfile',
        buttonText: 'Открыть'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Сохранить',
        handler: function(){
            if(loadfile.getForm().isValid()){
    //alert('Имя: '+loadfile.getForm().findField('userfile').getValue());
                    loadfile.getForm().submit({
                        url: '/test/file-upload.php',
                        waitMsg: 'Сохранение фотографии...',
                        success: function(loadfile, o){
                            msg('Success', 'Processed file "'+o.result.file+'" on the server');
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    },{
        text: 'Сброс',
        handler: function(){
            loadfile.getForm().reset();
             }
          }]
       });
```

file-upload.php:

```
 $uploaddir = '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/test/upload/000'//.$_GET["path"];
 if (!is_dir($uploaddir))
  {
    mkdir($uploaddir, 0777);
  }
 $uploaddir.='/';
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .
     $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
 echo $uploaddir;
 } else {
 echo "error";
}
```

and i have error in ext-all.js:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This error arises when your PHP code throws an error in HTML, and ExtJS is expecting JSON as a return, In order to get any further, you will need to open the javascript debugger and check the responses of the XHRs, one of the requests will give you more information about the error.

Comment: i fund this: "<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">&lt;?php
$uploaddir =                 '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/test/upload/'//.$_GET["path"];
      .......
         }
           ?&gt;
       </pre>"

Comment: looks like your server is not processing the PHP and is just returning it as plain text. are you sure mod_php is enabled in apache?

Comment: apache yes, but this html start from tomcat6